# String comparison in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, if-statement

I feel really stupid not be able to achieve this if.
I simply say, if: tag in my xml, "tipo" contains "Colonnina" do something

```
if ([[colonninaElencoFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:@"tipo"] = @"Colonnina" ){
do something ...
}
```

of course I know that you can not write so the syntax, this example brings us to better understand what I'm trying to do

needless to say that XML is written like

```
<tipo>Colonnina</tipo>
```

and I'm already using this method to extrapolate data from the xml such as this without any problem

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[colonninaElencoFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"title"]];
```

I hope you can help me, thanks

Comment: Are you missing the second equal sign in the comparison operator? == I mean.

Comment: Xcode is an IDE - the language is Objective-C.

Comment: I apologize to everyone I could read better the documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried something with `NSString isEqualToString:`?

```
if ([[[colonninaElencoFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:@"tipo"] isEqualToString:@"Colonnina"] ){
do something ...
}
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: xcode say "incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending NSString * to parameter of type NSUInteger (aka unsigned int)"

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([
       [colonninaElencoFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
             objectForKey:@"tipo"]
                   isEqualToString: @"Colonnina"] 
    ]){
       do something ...
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When comparing strings you should use **isEqualToString** method. Your comparison should look like this:

```
if ([[[colonninaElencoFeed objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:@"tipo"] isEqualToString:@"Colonnina"] ) {
do something ...
}
```

Comment: xcode say "incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending NSString * to parameter of type NSUInteger (aka unsigned int)"

Comment: I's because of _objectAtIndex:@"tipo"_. **index** parameter should be a number, not string