# Parsing NSString. How do I check for a specific string using if & else statements?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, nsstring

I'm parsing a venue element, but when one of the venues is not known it returns a value of "Unknown venue."
Some are known others are not. I've done the following so that I get all the values, but if it finds the "Unknown Venue" string, to replace it with "To Be Announced".

This is what I'm trying but it's not working:

```
if (event.venue != @"Unknown venue") {

    NSString *venue = event.venue;
    cell.venueLabel.text = venue;

    if (event.venue = @"Unknown venue") {

        NSString *venue = @"To Be Announced";
        cell.venueLabel.text = venue;
    }

}
```

Comment: What you doing isn't a comparison but an assignment in second case.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this code...

Comment: @Sulthan man I've been awake all night doing so many different things I completely forgot about the isEqualToString and went straight for the == or !==

Comment: I meant the other things. Please, see my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String comparison in Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875569/string-comparison-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the use of constants. However, `nil` would be better suited for "uknown" instead of a custom text.

```
#define VENUE_UNKNOWN @"Uknown venue"
#define VENUE_ANNOUNCED @"To Be Announced"

NSString *venue = event.venue;

if ([venue isEqualToString:VENUE_UNKNOWN]) {
    venue = VENUE_ANNOUNCED;
}

cell.venueLabel.text = venue;
```

Comment: I like that! Definitely will change it to that. The reason I rather set it to "to be announced" than nil is for interface purposes. Let's the user know that the venue will be announced later rather than completely hide it.

Comment: "to be announced" is clear. The problem is "uknown venue" which is not set to any UI label. Wouldn't `nil` be better there?

Comment: The string never returns nil, instead it returns "unknown venue" that's why I never used nil because it's technically not possible (assuming the parsing works correctly).

Answer (score 3):

```
if ([event.venue isEqualToString:@"Unknown venue"])
```

Answer (score 3):

Comparing strings should be done using

```
 [event.venue isEqualToString:@"yourstring"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below to replace with your code...

```
if ([event.venue isEqualToString:@"Unknown venue"]) {

        NSString *venue = @"To Be Announced";
        cell.venueLabel.text = venue;
}
else{
   NSString *venue = event.venue;
    cell.venueLabel.text = venue;
}
```

Comment: No it did work. He just forgot to enclose the event.venue isEqualToString:@"Unknown venue" inside "[]" Thank you Paras! You helped out!